How would I create these cuts/shapes on a rectangle?
How would you create these shapes on a rectangle ?The larger rectangle will have a video placed on it or image so it cant be many shapes placed together to form somewhat of a similar thing.

(the red stuff is not part of the design , i just added to draw attention to what I'm talking about)
I tried absolute positioning another element on top to create those ,but I couldn't achieve the rounding of the edges on the larger div etc...
Seen this figma design and I'm trying to replicate it , but have not made any progress.

I wouldn't! I'd use an SVG or a clip-path: path. CSS is way too underpowered for such a shape.

Ah that clip-path:path makes sense .Thanks !
